# Weird animation behaviour in landscape mode

Tags: android, animation

I have a **ListFragment** (support.v4) that only displays a **ListView**. When clicking on an element, an animation on that element starts. The animation is defined in **folder_animation_in_1.xml** (further explanation on the animation is given at bottom with screenshots):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true" >

    <scale 
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="5.0"
        android:toXScale="5.0"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:pivotX="100%"
        android:duration="250"/>

    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="250"/>
</set>
```

I start the animation in the **ListFragment** like this:

```
public void onListItemClick(final ListView l, final View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Animation expandAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.folder_animation_in_1);
    v.bringToFront();
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    v.setAnimation(expandAnim);         
    v.startAnimation(expandAnim);
}
```

This works fine as long as the orientation is portrait. As soon as the orientation changes to landscape mode, I'm getting a weird behaviour that I don't understand. The clicked element is suddenly moved to the last visible position in the ListView. Now the animation start from there.
I have also set up a tablet-emulator to really start the App in Landscape, because I thought there might be a problem due to orientation change itself. But the behaviour didn't change at all. Still the same problem.

Thanks for your help!

---

**UPDATE:**
I have made some testing with the following code:

```
public void onListItemClick(final ListView l, final View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    v.getDrawingRect(rect);
    int[] coord = new int[2];
    v.getLocationOnScreen(coord);
    Log.e(tag, "ListView-item: left: " + rect.left + ", right: "  + rect.right+ ", top: " + rect.top + ", bottom: " +  rect.bottom + ", Pos on Screen: " + coord[0] + ", " + coord[1]);

    View last = l.getChildAt(l.getLastVisiblePosition() - l.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    last.getDrawingRect(rect);
    last.getLocationOnScreen(coord);
    Log.e(tag, "ListView-item: left: " + rect.left + ", right: "  + rect.right+ ", top: " + rect.top + ", bottom: " +  rect.bottom + ", Pos on Screen: " + coord[0] + ", " + coord[1]);

    Animation expandAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.folder_animation_in_1);
    v.bringToFront();
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    v.setAnimation(expandAnim);         
    v.startAnimation(expandAnim);
    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            v.getDrawingRect(rect);
            int[] coord = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(coord);
            Log.e(tag, "ListView-item: left: " + rect.left + ", right: "  + rect.right+ ", top: " + rect.top + ", bottom: " +  rect.bottom + ", Pos on Screen: " + coord[0] + ", " + coord[1]);
        }
    }, animationDuration);
}
```

The output of the given test was:

```
ListView-item: left: 0, right: 683, top: 0, bottom: 100, Pos on Screen: 0, 269
ListView-item: left: 0, right: 683, top: 0, bottom: 100, Pos on Screen: 0, 677
ListView-item: left: 0, right: 683, top: 0, bottom: 100, Pos on Screen: 0, 677
```

I'm not sure how much this information helps, but it supports the visual perception of the effect - I really think the given element of the ListView is placed in the last visible position before animation starts. But why??

---

**Correct Animation Behaviour**

[image: Correct Animation Behaviour]

---

**Animation Behaviour in Landscape Mode**

[image: Real Behaviour in landscape mode]